# Error on remote task run with "schtasks /run /s"

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I want to run a task remotely. Therefore I created a .bat with

```
schtasks /run /s 111.20.123.160 /u Administrator /p password /tn "Task"
```

I just get an error: "FEHLER: Die Anforderung wird nicht unterstützt."
I also tried different users (normal and admin) and computername or IP.

My system: Win7, remote system: WinXP ... are there known issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. `schtasks` controls the new task scheduler introduced with Windows Vista. XP still uses the ancient one that dates back to Windows 2000. The respective capabilities are vastly different for one and the interface as well. So while both `at` and `schtasks` work on a current system (because the old interface is mapped onto the new one), XP simply does not *have* the new task scheduler version which `schtasks` manages. No surprise here that it simply won't work.

You can try doing the same with `at`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. <code>at</code> command now works good for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, you could also just copy the 'Schtasks' from XP and put it in another folder on the Windows 7 machine or put it in your 'System32' folder on the W7 box but rename it to 'XPSchedTask'. Then when you need to execute a scheduled task on a Windows XP box, you just call 'XPSchedTask' instead of 'SchedTask'